# How to properly report if X & ( Y<1 or Z>2 )

Tags: bash

I need some help with the script below, everything fails when it comes to third elif. I tried both < and -lt, both fail. I don't know what to do anymore

```sh
#!/bin/bash
currenttime=`date +%H%M`
morning="1800"
evening="2000"
host=127.0.0.1

while true; do
ping -c 1 -w 5 $host &> /dev/null

if [[ $? != 0 && ($currenttime > $evening || $currenttime < $morning) ]] #Ping down, and later than evening, or earlier than morning
then
        echo -e "Ping down, later than evening, earlier than morning"
elif [[ $? != 2 && ($currenttime > $evening || $currenttime < $morning) ]] #Ping up, and (later than evening, or earlier than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is up, later than evening, earlier than morning"

elif [[ $? != 0 && ($currenttime < $evening || $currenttime > $morning) ]] #Ping down, and (earlier than evening, or later than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is down, and it is earlier than evening or later than morning"

elif [[ $? != 2 && ($currenttime < $evening || $currenttime > $morning) ]] #Ping up,and (earlier than evening, or later than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is up and it is earlier than evening, or later than morning"

else
        echo "WTF?"
fi

done
```

Comment: I assume you intend `$?` to represent the exit status of `ping`, but every command you run resets its value. Put `ping_status=$!` immediately after the call to ping, and use that instead of `$?` in your `if` statement.

Comment: @chepner Thanks! Fixed it by putting the command as a variable output

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
currenttime=`date +%H%M`
morning="1800"
evening="2000"
host=127.0.0.1

while true; do
PINGOUTPUT=`ping -c 1 -w 5 $host &> /dev/null; echo $?`

if [[ $PINGOUTPUT != 0 && ($currenttime > $evening || $currenttime < $morning) ]] #Ping down, and later than evening, or earlier than morning
then
        echo -e "Ping down, later than evening, earlier than morning"
elif [[ $PINGOUTPUT != 2 && ($currenttime > $evening || $currenttime < $morning) ]] #Ping up, and (later than evening, or earlier than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is up, later than evening, earlier than morning"

elif [[ $PINGOUTPUT != 0 && ($currenttime < $evening || $currenttime > $morning) ]] #Ping down, and (earlier than evening, or later than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is down, and it is earlier than evening or later than morning"

elif [[ $PINGOUTPUT != 2 && ($currenttime < $evening || $currenttime > $morning) ]] #Ping up,and (earlier than evening, or later than morning)
then
        echo -e "Ping is up and it is earlier than evening, or later than morning"

else
        echo "WTF?"
fi

done
```

Comment: Use `PINGOUTPUT=$?`. The assignment you're showing will include the output of the `ping` command itself making all your `!=` true. When you do use command substitution, don't use backticks- use `$()` instead. It's much more readable and easily nestable.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I am requiring the output of the ping command myself. Whenever the host disconnects, it'll respond with `1`

Answer (score 0):

For arithmetic comparisons you need to use`-eq`, `-lt`, etc. From `man bash`:

> ```
>   arg1 OP arg2
>           OP  is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic
>           binary operators return true if arg1 is equal to, not equal  to,
>           less  than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than
>           or equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2 may  be  positive
>           or negative integers.
> ```

Currently you're doing `$currenttime < $evening` which is a string comparison.

Comment: The OP's time strings are zero padded and will compare lexically just fine, but your point is a valid one. In Bash, however, I prefer to do integer comparisons using the operators that the OP is using and to do that one has to use `(( ))` instead of square brackets.